# PyCharm Python/Jupyter Notebook custom style sheet

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

PyCharm has nice integration of IPython notebooks. But it's styling is bit ugly, specially in Linux Mint. Does anyone know how to change the style sheet of in-app IPython notebook?

Specifically I need to change font-family and font-size of markdown cells.

I tried with changing default IPython CSS at `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom` Unfortunately it doesn't affect in-app PyCharm notebook styling.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!